# Significado de puntuación en este contexto

Tags: significado, significado-en-contexto

En el siguiente fragmento: "Lindo vestido lleva usted esta mañana, señorita; la hace aún más atractiva... No se acalore. Lo he dicho solamente para que se sintiera contenta. En adelante, desearía que tuviera algo más de  cuidado con la **puntuación**"

¿Qué significado tendría la palabra "puntuación"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El texto completo dice que el presidente Calvin Coolidge hizo ese comentario a una de sus secretarias. Hace referencia a que para mostrarle un error en su trabajo, particularmente en ortografía y precisamente en el mal uso de la **puntuación** en los textos dictados, le dirigió una alabanza previa halagando su vestido.